# Cómo hacer que las filas de una matriz sean 0 en un for?

Tags: python

Buen día, quería hacer una matriz de 5x5 y luego que fila por medio sea igual a 0, algo como

```
0 0 0 0 0
3 2 5 4 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 5 9 1 2
0 0 0 0 0
```

o algo por el estilo, pero solo pude hacer que las columnas sean iguales a 0 osea

```
0 6 0 1 0 
0 3 0 5 0 
0 2 0 4 0
0 2 0 2 0
0 8 0 4 0
```

Con este código de aquí para hacer la matriz de 5x5

```
for i in range(5):
    matriz.append(([]))
    for j in range(5):
        x = random.randint(1, 9)
        matriz[i].append(0)
        matriz[i].append(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Una solución simple es agregar un `if` para comparar el número de fila con una condición, por ejemplo `fila%2 == 0` eso detectará todas las filas con índice par (Incluyendo la primera fila con índice 0)

Por cierto, tu código no devuelve la matriz de 5x5 que mencionas en tu pregunta

Ejemplo completo:

```
import random

matriz = []
for fila in range(5):
    matriz.append([])
    for columna in range(5):
        x = random.randint(1, 9)
        if fila%2 == 0:
            matriz[fila].append(0)
        else:
            matriz[fila].append(x)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 4, 7, 6, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 3, 5, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```